# UIImage only appears in table view cell when cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

So i'm using SWRevealViewController for a side menu on my application.

This is my side view controller:

```
import UIKit

class SideTableViewController: UITableViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
  }

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
      let cell: FirstTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FirstCell") as! FirstTableViewCell
      cell.textLabel?.text = "First Cell"
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
      cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
      cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: "person")
//      cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "person")
      cell.setNeedsLayout()
      return cell
    } else {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!
      cell.textLabel?.text = "Other Cell"
      cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
      cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
      return cell
    }
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
      return 200
    } else {
      return 50
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my custom table view cell i'm using called FirstTableViewCell:

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var cellImage: UIImageView!
}
```

When I open the side table view I see only a little bit of my image: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myV39.png)

But when I select my cell I can see the entire image!: [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctwhO.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

have to tried replacing

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
```

to

```
cell.setNeedsDisplay()
```